# Error: java.lang.NullPointerException in Client with WebService. How fixed it?

Tags: spring, jax-ws

I'm doing a example about jax-ws-spring-integration. My project have following structure.

[image]

**In Client**

[image]

Here file UserClient.java

```
public class UserClient {
    static UserService service;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      System.out.println("From webservice"
//              + service.sayHello("Nguyen van a")); 
        service = new UserService();
        User user = service.getUser("hoaipham");
        System.out.println("Hello" + user.getUserName());
        System.out.println("Email" + user.getAge()); 
    }

}
```

Here file UserService.java

```
@WebService
@Component
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserBo userBo;
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getUser")
    public User getUser(String username){
        return userBo.loadUser(username);
    }
    @WebMethod(operationName = "say")
    public String sayHello(String name){
        return "Hanoi Java say hello to" + name;
    }
}
```

When i run "main" in Client then occur following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   edu.java.spring.ws.UserService.getUser(UserService.java:19)   at
>   Client.UserClient.main(UserClient.java:14)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it looks like Spring not working in the Client (in a different jvm).

Try to create a instance of [AnnotationConfigApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html) and add your class to the Context (or let the instance scan the package).

**EDIT:**

Try

```
public class UserClient {
    static UserService service;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      System.out.println("From webservice"
//              + service.sayHello("Nguyen van a")); 
        service = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(UserService.class)
                          .getBean(UserService.class);
        User user = service.getUser("hoaipham");
        System.out.println("Hello" + user.getUserName());
        System.out.println("Email" + user.getAge()); 
    }

}
```

Comment: @Perter Rader, I have tried with my way. But occur new error. I have added this error on my post

Comment: @DatPham Sure, a not-existing context can not autowire `userBo`, so its `null`! Because of `null` has no method "`loadUser`" a exception occours. If you have a context (like `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`) the context can autowire the `@Autowired` field of bound classes and its not `null` anymore and you can call `loadUser`.